# Hash rate required to effectively mine an average of 1 block a day?

Tags: hashrate, solo-mining

What is the hash rate required to solo mine an average of 1 Monero Block per day using the current network stats?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently the network hashrate is [approximately 22.9 MH/s](http://moneroblocks.info/). There are about 30 blocks per hour and 720 blocks per day.

On average to find one block per day you would need 1/720 of the current network hashrate or approximately (22.9 MH/s)/(720) = 31.8 kH/s today. The relationship between MH and kH is [found here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/what-is-the-difference-between-kh-s-mh-s-and-gh-s)